# How to extract the exact word from a string while reducing false positive discovery

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to extract the exact word from a string. My code causes false discovery by considering the search item as a substring. Here is the code:

```
import re
text="Hello I am not react-dom"
item_search=['react', 'react-dom']

Found_item=[]
for i in range(0, len(item_search)):
    Q=re.findall(r'\b%s\b'%item_search[i], text, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)
    Found_item.append(Q)
    
print(Found_item)
```

The output is: `[['react'], ['react-dom']]`. So, In the result, I dont want to see the `react` as item.

The expected Output is: `[[''], ['react-dom']]`

Comment: In the case of `text="Hello I am not react-dime"`, do you expect an empty list or `["react"]`?

Comment: The item `react` should not be in the final result since its not an independent word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` is used to to indicate the boundary between types. eg between words and punctuations etc. so `\b` will be present between `t` from react and `-`. Thus here since we need whole words, we just use a lookbehind and lookahead to ensure that there no non-space between the two( THis is not the same as saying there is  a space between the two). Thus you could use:

```
 re.findall(rf"(?<!\S)({'|'.join(item_search)})(?!\S)", text)
['react-dom']
```

Edit:
If you were to include other non-word stuff like periods in the sentence, check [@DYZ comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840101/how-to-extract-the-exact-word-from-a-string-while-reducing-false-positive-discov/63840199?noredirect=1#comment112890373_63840199) then you could use:

`(?<!\S)({'|'.join(item_search)})\W*(?!\S)`

Comment: Your solution does not work if any item is immediately followed or preceded by punctuation, e.g. `"Hello I am not react-dom."`

Comment: @DYZ if you were to include that, then the regex would change to `(?<!\S)({'|'.join(item_search)})\W*(?!\S)`

Comment: I am not sure how important it is to the OP, but it still does not work for `"Hello I am not.react-dom"`

Comment: @DYZ it works since it returns an empty list. it should of course return empty list since we do not have `not.react-dom` in the list. we only have `react-dom` and `react`. Its like saying it should capture `react-dom` in `not:react-dom`. But that would be incorrect since it will be a `substring`. We do not need a substring .

Comment: Hello, dear answers One point I noticed that if the text is `Hello I am not /react-dom`, the regular can not find the `react-dom`. Please help to modify it.

Comment: @SyfulIslam just use `(?<!\S)\W*({'|'.join(item_search)})\W*(?!\S)`